# Android: How to change the position of ImageView dynamically?

Tags: android

I want my arrows to continuously move left and right with a delay of certain milliseconds dynamically. Any clue?

Here's my code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class PlayWithGraphics extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

 public final int delay = 2500;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        final ImageView iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv);
        iv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.back_two);

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){ 


          //iv.setPadding(30, 0, 10, 0);   
            }
        }, delay); 




  }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could either use a translate animation and update the movement in the `onRepeatListener` or put your image in a `RelativeLayout` and change its margin at regular intervals.

Comment: Now you gave 2 suggestions:
1.  use a translate animation and update the movement in the onRepeatListener  OR
2. put your image in a RelativeLayout and change its margin at regular intervals
For number 1: do you have a code example that you can post here or refer a tutorial on the web? 

For number 2: id don't have the required method available to me at runtime. I used setPadding but it didn't work. setMarginLeft and setMarginRight are only available at design time in XML layout.

Comment: Well, about method 2, actually no, these methods are clustered into one that you will find in `LayoutParams` from `RelativeLayout`. You just have to use a background thread which does the counting and every now and then, you change the margins. I'll have a go a that this afternoon and try to come back with some code/screenshot. Though I think the translate animation is the easiest way to do that... You refer to the translate animation in ApiDemo. or simply create your own instance. Again I'll have a look and give you more details later.